# Understand $\log_2 (x) < x$ proof in an article

Tags: logarithms

I am trying to understand a proof given in a solutions manual for "Datastructures and Algorithm Analysis in C" as seen in the screen shot. I am not able to understand the last few steps where it changes to $\log(Y/2)$ instead of $\log(Y+1).$

Any help to understand it is greatly appreciated.

Here's the question
[image]

Here's the proof
[image]

Comment: How big is $Y$?

Comment: $$\log_2(Y) = \log_2\left(2\cdot\frac Y2\right) = \log_2(2) + \log_2\left(\frac Y2\right) = 1 + \log_2\left(\frac Y2\right)$$

Comment: From [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question): The key parts of your question should not be in an embedded image such as a photo/screenshot/etc., such images are not searchable, they are not accessible to those using screen readers, and they don't show up in question summaries.

Answer (score 1):

The induction is not on $Y,$ it is on $p.$

It is an unusually stated induction. More verbosely, we will write it this way:

> **Claim:** For any integer $n\geq 0,$ and all real $Y$ with
> $2^n<Y\leq 2^{n+1},$ $$\log Y<Y.$$

The proof proves $n=0,$ then assumes true for $n$.

If $2^{n+1}<Y\leq 2^{n+2},$ then $2^{n}<\frac Y2\leq 2^{n+1}$ so, by the induction hypothesis, $$\log(Y/2)<Y/2$$
and then uses $Y>2^{n+1}\geq 2$ to prove $$\log(Y)<Y.$$

---

This claim assumes that you can prove:

> For all real $Y>1,$ there exists a non-negative integer $n$ such that $$2^n< Y\leq 2^{n+1}.$$

Otherwise it wouldn’t be proven for all $Y>1.$

The claim itself only proves for $Y>1,$ but the book proves $0<Y\leq1$ separately.

---

We can find $n$ from $Y$ as $$n=\begin{cases}\log Y-1& \log Y\text{ is an integer}\\\lfloor\log Y\rfloor&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Where $\lfloor \cdot\rfloor$ is the greatest integer function, and the values are always non-negative integers because $\log Y>0.$

Comment: Thanks. But trying to understand why did they switched to  log(Y/2) why not log(Y + 1) ?

Comment: Okay, I’ve edited my answer to conform to your real confusion.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Now it makes perfect sense.

Comment: Also @Thomas Andrews it would be great if you can elaborate more on how to prove  the last statement. $\log(Y)<Y$ when $Y>2^{n+1}\geq 2$. Is this how to prove it $\log(2^{n + 2}/2)\lt 2^{n+2}/2$ which in turn simplifies to $\log(2^{n + 1})\lt 2^{n+1}$ . Thus proving the theorem ?

Comment: That was in the book’s proof. @jnxd A little more elaborately: Since it is true for $Y/2,$ $$\log Y=\log 2+\log(Y/2)=1+\log(Y/2)<1+Y/2<Y/2+Y/2=Y.$$